# 6 Regions Custom Choropleth USA Map in Python

Tags: python, visualization, heatmap

I'd like to create a Choropleth map of USA with 6 regions like in the map below. Does anyone have a similar map I could re-use?
Much appreciated!

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvy0w.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBMGo.png)

I expect to produce a USA map with 6 regions. Then plug in data to shot total counts in each of the regions and color grading.

Comment: Please provide description for image link

Comment: Hi Tony, I tried editing the post and I'm not sure if I did it right but it's the image at the bottom of this site - https://basketballnoise.com/what-are-the-6-nba-divisions/ or if you google NBA 6 divisions you'll get an idea. Thanks a million.